# Is there a React-Native FlatList forEach?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Is there a React-Native FlatList forEach? What I am trying to achieve basically is, I have a `FlatList` and I want to add an animation on each item, and when the animation finishes the next item gets rendered. Or at least, render an item, make it wait a second and then renders the next item... 
There also won't be an optimisation problem because the list I'm rendering in the given screen always only has 3 items

Comment: The renderItem function is called in a for each for the items that are visible (or will be visible), you can try animating inside the renderItem function.

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to mutate the FlatList component directly, as it is a native view component. You should always mutate the data source and change its state. Be aware, if you do this too often, you risk performance issues, because you will trigger re-rendering on every change.

All you need to do is to animate your list item e.g:

```
class ListItem extends PureComponent {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            animateItem: new Animated.Value(0)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.animateItem, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 300,
            delay: 300
        }).start()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View
                style={{
                    opacity: this.state.animateItem,
                    transform: [{
                        translateY: this.state.animateItem.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [0, 1],
                            outputRange: [500, 1]
                        })
                    }]
                }}>
                {/* child views here  */}
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}
```

This will animate your items from bottom to top. You can set `delay` property in `Animated.timing` method to delay animation. FlatList renders items one-by-one and they will also be animated like that as well.